# jquery - check if there are disabled elements, before or after

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `select` field with some disabled `option` elements in. 
With jQuery I want find any disabled element before or after selected `option`.
But when i choose `option` from the beginning or end of the list, which they don't have any disabled elements after or before, in result i still have message from condition where script should find both possibilities.

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option selected>-- select hour --</option>
  <option data-hour="1630" value="16:30">16:30</option>
  <option data-hour="1700" value="17:00">17:00</option>
  <option data-hour="1730" value="17:30" disabled>17:30</option>
  <option data-hour="1800" value="18:00" disabled>18:00</option>
  <option data-hour="1830" value="18:30" disabled>18:30</option>
  <option data-hour="1900" value="19:00">19:00</option>
  <option data-hour="1930" value="19:30" disabled>19:30</option>
  <option data-hour="2000" value="20:00" disabled>20:00</option>
  <option data-hour="2030" value="20:30">20:30</option>
  <option data-hour="2100" value="21:00">21:00</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**jQUery**

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

  var t = $(":selected", this);
  var thisSelected = $(":selected", this).data("hour");
  var result = $("#result");

  if ( t.prevUntil('option[disabled]') && !t.nextUntil('option[disabled]') ) {

    result.html(thisSelected + " HAVE PREV - NO NEXT " + t.prevUntil("option[disabled]").data("hour"));

  } else if ( !t.prevUntil('option[disabled]') && t.nextUntil('option[disabled]') ) {

    result.html(thisSelected + " HAVE NEXT - NO PREV " + t.nextUntil("option[disabled]").data("hour"));

  } else if ( t.nextUntil('option[disabled]') && t.prevUntil('option[disabled]') ) {

    result.html(thisSelected + " HAVE BOTH : " + t.prevUntil('option[disabled]').data('hour') + " || " + t.nextUntil('option[disabled]').data('hour') );

  }

});
```

**JsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/zbfu1wkh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No need to use `nextUntil()` or `prevUntil()` it'll be enough to use `prev()` and `next()` and check the `length` then get the `data-hour` of it
- Also to get the last `[disabled]` prev you can use `.prevAll()`

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {

  var t = $(":selected", this);
  var thisSelected = $(":selected", this).data("hour");
  var result = $("#result");
  var If_prev = t.prev('option[disabled]'); // previous disabled option
  var If_next = t.next('option[disabled]'); // next disabled option
  if(If_prev.length){ // if there is one disabled prev
    console.log('Prev data-hour '+If_prev.data("hour")); // get data-hour of prev
  }else{ // if there is no direct prev
    if(t.prevAll('option[disabled]').length){ // check for any prev
      console.log('No direct prev but Last disabled prev is '+t.prevAll('option[disabled]').data('hour')); // get the last disabled prev
    }
  }
  if(If_next.length){ // if there is one disabled after
    console.log('Next data-hour '+If_next.data("hour")); // get data-hour of next
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option selected>-- select hour --</option>
  <option data-hour="1630" value="16:30">16:30</option>
  <option data-hour="1700" value="17:00">17:00</option>
  <option data-hour="1730" value="17:30" disabled>17:30</option>
  <option data-hour="1800" value="18:00" disabled>18:00</option>
  <option data-hour="1830" value="18:30" disabled>18:30</option>
  <option data-hour="1900" value="19:00">19:00</option>
  <option data-hour="1930" value="19:30" disabled>19:30</option>
  <option data-hour="2000" value="20:00" disabled>20:00</option>
  <option data-hour="2030" value="20:30">20:30</option>
  <option data-hour="2100" value="21:00">21:00</option>

</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. It almost correct. I need also to have `If_prev` result when i choose last `option` from list which don't have disabled `option` elements right before, but there are several elements earlier. In this case `option` with "20:00" is first as disabled and it should also match into `If_prev` when i choose "21:00".

Comment: Thank You. I completely forgot about `length` because i almost never use it. And of course `prevAll()` function is also suprise for me.

Comment: You're totally welcome @X9DESIGN .. The snippet above gives you the values you need separately .. You'll need to play around this code to combine them in `$('#result')` text.. Have a great day :-)